# finding contours in opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

i am trying to find contours in a specific area of image in open-cv.
Below code performs it in c++.
How can i do this in python?
Pls save

```
findContours( img(cv::Rect(x,y,width,height)), contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0,0) );
```

Comment: See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0

Comment: contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours( image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]] ) @fmw42 it shows this  it is giving errors

Comment: The output format for cv.findContours() is different for different versions of OpenCV. Also for my install I use cv2 not cv.  But that also is install dependent. What is your version of OpenCV. What was the error message! Where did it occur?  Post more of your code and what you actually wrote for findContours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).